# box2d falling while moving

Tags: c++, box2d, game-development

Hey my player isn't falling while I'm pressing any of movement inputs while I'm falling. Just stands still and moves right or left.

Just watch the video; [Video](https://streamable.com/gu9eg5)

My movement code;

```
if (right == true) {
    p_pBody.body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(5, 0));
}
else
{
    p_pBody.rect.setPosition(p_xPos * s_METPX, p_yPos * s_METPX); // Set The SFML Graphics
}
if (left == true) {
    p_pBody.body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(-5, 0));
}
else
{
    p_pBody.rect.setPosition(p_xPos * s_METPX, p_yPos * s_METPX); // Set The SFML Graphics
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the vertical velocity to 0 when you're pressing right or left. That's the second coordinate of `b2Vec2`. If you want to have gravity, replace that zero with the vertical velocity the block has when the buttons are not being pressed.

Comment: How can i calculate the vertical velocity. I didn't understand well. (EDIT) okey nvm i replaced the 0 with p_pBody.body->GetLinearVelocity().y thanks.